# Is it possible to use one-time passwords for WI-FI?

Tags: wifi, one-time-password

Is it possible to configure an access point to use [one-time passwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password) for authentication and encryption ?

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your question to change it into a technical question (is it possible and how ?) rather than a product recommendation which would be off-topic here. If you disagree feel free to rollback my edit.

Answer (score 3):

You could configure the access point to use WPA2-Enterprise and then configure your radius server to use OTP as a password.

This would mean the user enters the OTP as a password. One thing to note, is that the client does not know its a OTP and might save the profile (which will not work next time since the OTP is spent), thus causing headaches for the users.

One thing im curious about: Why use OTP for Wifi at all if its not for hotspot payment?
A better idea would be to use a general group password to access the hotspot and the internet, but when you want to access other services (for example, internal servers, intranets, secure storage etc(, you have to authenticate to a webpage to gain access through a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

For simple authentication many vendors propose this in the form of a captive portal that asks users for an OTP before allowing them access to the Internet. However, this doesn't protect the actual Wi-Fi network and if it's an open hotspot (no encryption), then users can still eavesdrop on each other's traffic and impersonate each other to the eyes of the AP by spoofing their MAC address.

Another solution involves both authentication and encryption of the wireless signal, called [EAP-POTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol#EAP-POTP) requires an OTP to connect to the network, and all wireless traffic is encrypted no matter what kind of protocols you use (thus using HTTP over this would be fine). It doesn't involve a horrible captive portal which means that you have to enter the OTP directly via your device's OS, which is faster and more user-friendly. Unfortunately that technology isn't popular enough (a search doesn't yield many results besides an RFC and some enterprise router manufacturer sites) and I don't know if it's supported in most OSes we use today.

Comment: I personally disagree with the first solution since captive portals are obnoxious and having to open a browser for authentication every time you connect to the network is so annoying and time wasting.

Answer (score 0):

As sebastian nielsen pointed out, you should use a RADIUS server to authenticate with OTP.
I disagree using a group password. If you want to distinguish users or deny access for single users one day, you should use individual authentication like OTP(RADIUS) or Client Certificates.

OTP provide headache, since the OTP will not be valid a second time (as pointed out by sebastian) but on the other hand client certificates need to be renewed after the validity period and might be more complicated to enroll to the users.

So you can choose, which scenario fits best for you.

Comment: The reason I suggested using a Group password, is that you could use layered security. Eg for internet access - only a Group password to keep strangers out. Its not really a big concern if this password leaks out. But to access more sensitive servers, OTP is required. With this, I mean that the wifi should be placed logically on the "internet" side of the firewall, so all users connecting via wifi will be required to authenticate to internal servers like they were coming from the internet. Thus, only thing that happens if someone gains unauthorized access to wifi: Internet access.